# Firebase push notification not working in background and app is inactive in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implemented on `FCM` in `swift 3.0`. `FCM` notification is working if my application is in foreground properly, but notification is not getting if application is in background or in inactive state. I have implemented all the steps provided by firebase, below function getting called only app is active.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

Please suggest if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: can you post payload?????

Comment: That is expected behavior: when your app is in the background, the system will handle the notification. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171663/linking-custom-auth-provider-with-firebase, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600914/push-notification-not-received-when-app-is-in-background-in-ios-10 and probably a few more on this list: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D%5Bios%5D+background

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your reply, do you have any idea about app is in inactive state how can we handle push notification.

Comment: If you always want to handle the message in your own code, send data message (as opposed to notification messages).

Comment: @pannamanikpure have you got the solution for this? i am also facing the same problem

Comment: @ Ganesh Kumar I am facing same problem not get solution yet

Comment: @ Ganesh Kumar Not get any solution yet