# How to get local notification when app is running in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to show local notification when app is running.
My code is like this

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; //Enter the time here in seconds.
localNotification.alertBody = @"Message hear";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute; //Repeating instructions here.
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

I write this code on the button click but it is not showing me notification.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If the app is running, why would you show a notification? The notification is a way to make the user start the app. Why would you do that if the app is already running?

Answer (score 3):

No it does not show if you use above code.First of all I want to ask some questions.

`Does your above code work if you use iOS 10?`

`Where do you call above lines of code in your class or in which method do you apply?`

iOS 10 has new framework called `UNUserNotification`.We have to import the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` for showing UILocalNotification when app is running.

> The [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate?language=objc)  protocol defines methods for
>   responding to actionable notifications and receiving notifications
>   while your **app is in the foreground**. You assign your delegate object
>   to the delegate property of the shared UNUserNotificationCenter
>   object. The user notification center object calls methods of your
>   delegate at appropriate times to deliver information.

Then when notification arrives it calls [willPresentNotification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter?language=objc)

> If your app is in the foreground when a notification arrives, the
>   notification center calls below method

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center 
   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification 
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler;
```

> Above method  delivers the notification
>   directly to your app. If you implement this method, you can take
>   whatever actions are necessary to process the notification and update
>   your app. When you finish, execute the completionHandler block and
>   specify how you want the system to alert the user, if at all. If your
>   delegate does not implement this method, the system silences alerts as
>   if you had passed the UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone option to
>   the completionHandler block. If you do not provide a delegate at all
>   for the UNUserNotificationCenter object, the system uses the
>   notification’s original options to alert the user.

`How can you show the notification?`

For achieving this we have 3 options

```
Sound
Badge
Alert
```

[UNNotificationPresentationOptions help us to implement this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptions?language=objc)

Above is the good one to understand and do.

I preferred some answers also. They are

[Show iOS notification when app is running](https://blog.jayway.com/2016/12/09/show-ios-notification-app-running/)

[Displaying a stock iOS notification banner when your app is open and in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852870/displaying-a-stock-ios-notification-banner-when-your-app-is-open-and-in-the-fore)

[Getting local notifications to show while app is in foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713605/getting-local-notifications-to-show-while-app-is-in-foreground-swift-3)

[Notification while app is in foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios)

[Notification in iOS 10](http://ashishkakkad.com/2016/09/push-notifications-in-ios-10-objective-c/)

[Local Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941778/how-to-schedule-a-local-notification-in-ios-10-objective-c)

[didReceiveRemoteNotification not called , iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10)

Answer (score 1):

you have to add this code

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability| UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

if you set this then you have to change this line

```
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; //Enter the time here in seconds.
```

when you tap on button set notification but you cannot show because you app in active state and replace 0 to 60  time interval and put your app background and check

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
NSTimeInterval interval;
interval = 60* 60* 12;//12 hours from now
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];//Enter the time here in seconds.
localNotification.alertBody= @"This is message Users will see";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.repeatInterval= NSCalendarUnitMinute;//NSCalendarUnitMinute; //Repeating instructions here.
localNotification.soundName= UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. Can you give more explanation to make your response more usefull.

Comment: But the notification gets repeated if you dont want like that replace the line with this code                                                                      localNotification.fireDate= [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:5];