# didReceiveRemoteNotification not called in Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added firebase in my objective-C project. Integrated successfully, but I can't show notification in notification bar of iPhone.

when notification arrived this method is called and i get data there..

```
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {

    NSLog(@"FCM Received data message: >> %@", [remoteMessage appData]);


 }
```

But this method didn't call...

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your payload contains `notification` key like this

```
{
    "to" : " ...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
```

Without `notification` key in your payload `didRecieveRemoteNotification` method will not trigger.

Check these for more info [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)  [2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

Comment: {
    "collapse_key" = "bundle id";
    from = 23123213;
    notification =     {
        badge = 1;
        body = "body is here";
        e = 1;
        icon = myicon;
        sound = default;
        sound2 = "defalut sound";
        subtitle = 1;
        title = "teasdfasasdf ";
    };
}

Comment: Which iOS version are you using. If you are using iOS 10.0 or more check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600914/push-notification-not-received-when-app-is-in-background-in-ios-10

Comment: in iOS11 didRecieveRemoteNotification method will not work. you need to handle userNotifications framework

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: Check  this question I have explained here fully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600914/push-notification-not-received-when-app-is-in-background-in-ios-10